# Execution failed for task ':app:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[image]In my react-native project when i run the command (yarn android or npx react-native run-android)
.cxx file is created in android/app folder

and that file can't build my app in android what’s the solution .

I am try to build my project and also trying to remove the .cxx file in my project/android/app folder . I found my solution but it can't work for me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the main problem is that when i run the project .cxx file is generated in my project app folder 
showing me this warning :
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

error:
Execution failed for task ':app:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.